# Remove words in one column if present in another column

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is in this format:

```
A <- c("John Smith", "Red Shirt", "Family values are better")
B <- c("John is a very highly smart guy", "We tried the tea but didn't enjoy it at all", "Family is very important as it gives you values")

df <- as.data.frame(A, B)
```

My intention is to get the result back as:

```
ID   A                           B
1    John Smith                  is a very highly smart guy
2    Red Shirt                   We tried the tea but didn't enjoy it at all
3    Family values are better    is very important as it gives you
```

I have tried:

```
test<-df %>% filter(sapply(1:nrow(.), function(i) grepl(A[i], B[i])))
```

But this doesn't get me the desired output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to use `mapply` along with `strsplit`.

The trick is to split `df$A` in separate words and collapse those words separated by `|` and then use it as `pattern` in `gsub` to replace with `""`.

```
lst <- strsplit(df$A, split = " ")

df$B <- mapply(function(x,y){gsub(paste0(x,collapse = "|"), "",df$B[y])},lst,1:length(lst))
df
# A                                           B
# 1               John Smith                  is a very highly smart guy
# 2                Red Shirt We tried the tea but didn't enjoy it at all
# 3 Family values are better          is very important as it gives you
```

Another option is as:

```
df$B <- mapply(function(x,y)gsub(x,"",y) ,gsub(" ", "|",df$A),df$B)
```

**Data:**

```
A <- c("John Smith", "Red Shirt", "Family values are better")
B <- c("John is a very highly smart guy", "We tried the tea but didn't enjoy it at all", "Family is very important as it gives you values")

df <- data.frame(A, B, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Great answer @MKR, it worked fine in my case. You second option worked slightly faster in my case. I am working with a couple of million lines data.frame. Any clues if an approach based on data.table would be more time efficient?

Comment: This worked for me by switching the `$A` and `$B`. Thanks! How would I remove only the part that is not matching?

Answer (score 2):

Just another option using `stringr::str_split_fixed` function:

```
library(stringr)

str_split_fixed(sapply(paste(df$A,df$B, sep=" columnbreaker "), 
                function(i){
                            paste(unique(
                                         strsplit(as.character(i), split=" ")[[1]]), 
                         collapse = " ")}), 
                 " columnbreaker ", 2)


#       [,1]                       [,2]                                         
# [1,] "John Smith"               "is a very highly smart guy"                 
# [2,] "Red Shirt"                "We tried the tea but didn't enjoy it at all"
# [3,] "Family values are better" "is very important as it gives you"
```

Comment: This worked out as well. Thank you. Though I feel the above solution is more elegant and suits my need (I have a huge dataset)

Comment: Revisiting this 5 years later...  While "less elegant", @M--'s solution worked for me while the accepted answer did not.  I found that the accepted answer did not limit itself to full words, but clipped words and returned fragments.   For example, 

`mapply(function(x,y)gsub(x,"",y) ,gsub(" ", "|","PHYCIS CHESTERI"),"UROPHYCIS CHESTERI")` 
returns "URO ", when it is expected to return "UROPHYCIS".